# xinput: How to set integer value correctly?

Tags: xorg, touchpad

I wish to update the `Synaptics Pad Resolution` of my Apple Magic Trackpad.

On `xinput list-props "Apple Wireless Trackpad"` I get:

```
...
Synaptics Pad Resolution (642): 45, 46
...
```

If I try to change that or even set the same values again, I get:

```
xinput set-prop "Apple Wireless Trackpad" "Synaptics Pad Resolution" 45 46
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)                                                 
  Major opcode of failed request:  142 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Value in failed request:  0x282
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  21
```

How am I supposed to set these integer parameters on my touchpad?

Comment: PS: It would be nice if somebody with the needed reputation could create an `xinput` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that nothing is wrong with this xinput invocation - the error message is just misleading.

`Synaptics Pad Resolution` has been made read-only in https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18351#c33 and trying to set it now returns `BadValue` (`integer parameter out of range` is obviously misleading when `property is readonly` is meant).

Also see comment #23 in https://bugs.launchpad.net/xorg-driver-synaptics/+bug/726832.

A [patch has been committed](http://patchwork.freedesktop.org/patch/12839/) in early 2013.

Comment: Yes, very misleading!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the error `BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)` if you separate the parameters with commas instead of spaces.  You will often see xinput help threads on the internet suggest commas as parameter separators because older versions of xinput accepted commas as parameter separators, but no longer.

So for instance, instead of this:

```
xinput set-prop 10 154 3,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,1
```

I had to run this:

```
xinput set-prop 10 154 3 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1
```